# No animations shown when restoring a minimized window on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, compiz

I don't see the minimizing animation while minimizing the window, I see the animation only when I reopen the window after it has been minimized

Comment: Have you set animations? Why tagged nvidia?

Answer (score 0):

Unity Tweak Tool is useful for tweaking preferences. (To install type `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` in terminal)

Then You can tweak animations from **Window Manager General** option.

[image: animations-tweak]